# Non-greedy regex not matching as expected

Tags: python, regex

Given the following string as input:

```
[2015/06/09 14:21:59] mod=syn|cli=192.168.1.99/49244|srv=192.168.1.100/80|subj=cli|os=Windows 7 or 8|dist=0|params=none|raw_sig=4:128+0:0:1460:8192,8:mss,nop,ws,nop,nop,sok:df,id+:0
```

I'm trying to match the value of `subj`, ie: in the above case the expected output would be `cli`

I don't understand why my regex is not working:

```
subj = re.match(r"(.*)subj=(.*?)|(.*)", line).group(2)
```

From what I can tell, the second group in here should be `cli` but I'm getting an empty result.

Comment: As a side note, you want to use `search()` instead of `match()` to get rid of the leading `(.*)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zJ1bY4/1)

I'd recommend using the following regex, because it will provide better performance with two additions/substitutions:

- adding the beginning of line character `^`
- adding the negating group `[^\|]*` is faster than `(.*)?`

**Code**

```
subj = re.match(r"^.*\|subj=([^\|]*)", line).group(1)
```

**regex:**

```
^.*\|subj=([^\|]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/irH9utttix3rDbhS)

Answer (score 3):

The `|` has special meaning in regex (Which creates [alternations](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) ) , hence escape it as

```
>> re.match(r"(.*)subj=(.*?)\|", line).group(2)
'cli'
```

---

**Another Solution**

You can use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) so that you can get rid of the groups at the start of `subj` and that after the `|`

**Example**

```
>>> re.search(r"subj=(.*?)\|", line).group(1)
'cli'
```

Here we use `group(1)` since there is only one group that is being captured instead of three as in previous version.

- [Read about the differences between `search` and `match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

---

**Complex version**

You can even get rid of all the capturing if you are using [look arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
>>> re.search(r"(?<=subj=).*?(?=\|)", line).group(0)
'cli'
```

- `(?<=subj=)` Checks if the string matched by `.*?` is preceded by `subj`.
- `.*?` Matches anything, non greedy matching.
- `(?=\|)` Check if this *anything* is followed by a `|`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `|`.. Use the following:

```
subj = re.match(r"(.*)subj=(.*?)\|(.*)", line).group(2)
                                ^
```

Answer (score 1):

The pipe sign `|` needs to be escaped, like so:

`subj = re.match(r"(.*)subj=(.*?)\|(.*)", s).group(2)`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a negated class `[^|]*` with `re.search` for better performance:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^(.*)subj=([^|]*)\|(.*)$')
test_str = "[2015/06/09 14:21:59] mod=syn|cli=192.168.1.99/49244|srv=192.168.1.100/80|subj=cli|os=Windows 7 or 8|dist=0|params=none|raw_sig=4:128+0:0:1460:8192,8:mss,nop,ws,nop,nop,sok:df,id+:0"
print re.search(p, test_str).group(2)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Z6a1Ex)

Note I am not using both lazy and greedy quantifiers in the regex (it is not advisable usually).

The pipe symbol must be escaped to be treated as a literal `|` symbol.

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

- `^` - Start of string
- `(.*)` - The first capturing group that matches characters from the beginning up to
- `subj=` - A literal string `subj=`
- `([^|]*)` - The second capturing group matching any characters other than a literal pipe (inside a character class, it does not need escaping)
- `\|` - A literal pipe (must be escaped)
- `(.*)` - The third capturing group (if you need to get the string after up to the end.
- `$` - End of string